# multiple recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I understand  simple recursion, but I'm having a hard time understanding multiple recursion. can someone illustrate the order of execution of multiple recursion for this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
  int data;
  node * next;
  node();
  node(node* &o):data(o->data){};
  node(int a):data(a),next(NULL){};
};
void initialize(node *& head){
  head = new node(0);
  node *temp(head);
  for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    temp->next = new node(i);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
void function(node* head, int index){
  if(index >= 3){
    cout << "you hit the base case" << endl;
    return;
  }
  else if(index < 3){
     cout << "Before first call" << endl; 
     function(head->next, index+1);                     //call one
     cout << "After he first call" << endl;
     function(head->next, index+1);                     //call two
     cout << "After the second call" << endl;
  }
}
int main() {
  node * head = nullptr;
  int index = 1;
  initialize(head);
  function(head, index);
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Add an output statement at the beginning of ```function()```, that will tell you current values of ```head``` and ```index```.

Comment: Using the debugger of you IDE is the best way to figure out how the code is executed. There you can step through each instruction.

Comment: oh, I never thought of that; that'd solve it.  I was compiling it on repl. Thanks a lot